# iam have code php and get this error Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code:

```
 $evaluationjob = evaluation_elements_jobs::where('job_id', $user->job_id)
          ->where('company_id',$company_check->id)
          ->first();
```

The error in this line:

```
         $items = json_decode($evaluationjob["element_degree"]);
```

The error message is:

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Comment: check if $evaluationjob["element_degree"] is null

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$evaluationjob = evaluation_elements_jobs::where('job_id', $user->job_id)
      ->where('company_id',$company_check->id)
      ->first();

if ($evaluationjob != null && isset($evaluationjob["element_degree"])) {
    $items = json_decode($evaluationjob["element_degree"]);
}
```

This will check if `$evaluationjob` is not null and if the value `$evaluationjob["element_degree"]` exists in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are having here is the fact that you're trying to access a property on a variable that is null;

So you need to put a check on the variable and the property.

```
if ($evaluationjob != null && isset($evaluationjob["element_degree"])) {
    $items = json_decode($evaluationjob["element_degree"]);
}
```